# find a word in a sentence using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

So, I am trying to find a word (a complete word) in a sentence. Lets say the sentence is

```
Str1 = "1. how are you doing"
```

and that I am interested in finding if

```
Str2 = "1."
```

is in it. If I do,

```
re.search(r"%s\b" % Str2, Str1, re.IGNORECASE)
```

it should say that a match was found, isn't it? but the `re.search` fails for this query. why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things wrong here:

1. `\b` matches a position between a word and a non-word character, so between any letter, digit or underscore, and a character that doesn't match that set.

   You are trying to match the boundary between a `.` and a space; both are *non-word* characters and the `\b` anchor would never match there.
2. You are handing `re` a `1.`, which means 'match a `1` and any other character'. You'd need to escape the dot by using [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to match a literal `.`.

The following works better:

```
re.search(r"%s(?:\s|$)" % re.escape(Str2), Str1, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Now it'll match your input literally, and look for a following space or the end of the string. The `(?:...)` creates a non-capturing group (always a good idea unless you specifically need to capture sections of the match); inside the group there is a `|` pipe to give two alternatives; either match `\s` (whitespace) or match `$` (end of a line). You can expand this as needed.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> Str1 = "1. how are you doing"
>>> Str2 = "1."
>>> re.search(r"%s(?:\s|$)" % re.escape(Str2), Str1, re.IGNORECASE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10457eed0>
>>> _.group(0)
'1. '
```

Comment: +1.  A couple of minor nits with the improved regex: 1) The trailing space is matched.  2) `Str1 = "11. No way!"` would match.

Comment: Great! could you please elaborate on the regular expression you use? would be helpful to understand.

Comment: @suzee:  Martijn may elaborate, but for now check out the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) and see if you can suss it out.  It's a great way to learn.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: the OP is low on detail on what the goal is; I had the impression it was more a boolean test (the expression matches or doesn't), which makes including the space in the matched output moot. The main problem here was that `\b` doesn't anchor where the OP expected it to anchor, but if a word character should be allowed *as well* as whitespace, you may as well just use `if Str2 in Str1:` and forgo regular expressions altogether.